# Why do we have $\overline{\operatorname{Mov}(X)}\subset \overline{\operatorname{Eff}(X)}$ for any normal variety $X$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

I am trying to understand why $\overline{\operatorname{Mov}(X)}\subset \overline{\operatorname{Eff}(X)}$, where $X$ is any normal variety.

Here $\operatorname{Mov}(X)$ is the convex cone generated by movable divisors in $N^1(X)$, and $\operatorname{Eff}(X)$ is the cone generated by effective divisors on $X$. A divisor is movable if $\operatorname{Codim}(B(D))\geq 2,$ where
$$B(D)=\cap_{m\geq 1}Bs(|mD|).$$
So essentially, I am trying to prove that any movable divisor is a limit of effective divisors. But I do not have any alternate description of movable divisors, which is making the task more difficult and non-intuitive.

Comment: I think "Why is every movable divisor on a normal variety a limit of effective divisors?" may make for a better title (less inscrutable).

Comment: We know that there exists $m_0>>0$, such that $B(D)=Bs(|m_0D|)$ (Prop. 2.1.21, [Positivity I, Lazarsfeld]). Hence $\operatorname{Codim}(Bs(|m_0D|))\geq 2,$ this means that $|m_0D|\neq \phi$, which proves that $m_0D$ and thus $D$ is effective.